# minecraft server is running on linux, nmap reports ports are open, on local lan. Can't connect to it

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server, linux

I'm running minecraft Server on Ubuntu 18.04 - the minecraft_server.jar. status says its running on the machine.  nmap shows its running and ports are open.  The local IP is 192.168.1.36 and the port is 25565.  I go to my other Linux scan that address and reports that indeed it is open and running.
I go to Windows 10 with purchased minecraft version 1.8.1 and put in the IP and port in the 2 separate fields. Can't connect.

Is there some other mystery setting to allow not localhost connections or something?

Comment: 1. Can you ping it (just normal `ping` command in the console)? 2. Does it work with 1.12.2?

Comment: yes, I can ping it, and using a different linux box I can nmap port scan and see the IP and port is open.  I can ping it from the windows machine.

Comment: I just ran a port scan From the Windows Machine with Minecraft Client installed and the IP and port 25565 are Open. So the physical box can connect.  The servers version is the latest 1.13.x.  Just downloaded today.  The 1.12.2 version did NOT work.  So I just downloaded the 1.13.x version today.  thx

Comment: What do you mean, it's fixed now? Then you can self-answer if you think it might possibly be useful for someone else in the future, otherwise delete.

Comment: No it does work yet.  The issue may be that you can't connect from a Windows 10 license of the game to a Java Server?  Do I need a Java client also?

Comment: I believed I have confirmed that this is the issue.  It would seem that Microsoft intends to fracture the user base.. and potentially ruin the overall experience, I'm sure to 'make it better' but a Windows 10 client can't connect to the Java server.

Comment: Oh, so you tried to run the "Windows 10 edition" client? Of course that can't work, it's a completely different game. Their mistake is not to "fracture the user base", it's the exact opposite, they're acting like it's all the same, even though the games have little to do with each other. They just make it look similar. It's like a bad ripoff. But why did you say "1.8" then? The MCPE version number hasn't reached 1.8 yet.

Answer (score 1):

There are currently two editions of Minecraft being actively developed:

- Java Edition - Available for Windows, Mac, Linux
- Bedrock Edition - Available for Windows 10 (UWP app on the Microsoft Store), Android, iOS, Xbox One, etc.

The players on the Java Edition can only connect to Java Edition servers, and the players on the Bedrock Edition can only connect to Bedrock Edition servers. (The platform / OS which on the game is running doesn't matter, except in the case of Xbox One, where there are some limitations for players without Xbox Live Gold.) You need to download the appropriate server for your edition.

Alternatively -, but this is not (yet) a good option - you can run a Minecraft: Java Edition Spigot server, which is an (indirect) fork of the original vanilla Minecraft server with some tweaks and support for plugins, install the ProtocolSupportPE plugin to allow Bedrock Edition players to connect to your Java Edition server. Please note that this is in heavy development, you will have to compile it yourself, and last time I've checked it out, it had a major bug with you not being able to see the player at the right location, but as time goes by, this solution might become reasonable, but I have referenced it in case somebody really needs it.

Answer (score -1):

A Windows 10 Minecraft client can't connect to a Java Server.  You need to buy the Java Client or pay for the microsoft server feature.